# How to let <a href..> not refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a div, which is in a link href tag:

```
<a href="banana.html"><div id="somediv">Some Div</div></a>
```

when I click on the div, the entire page unloads and reloads with banana.html. However, I'm using websocket and need only a part of the page to reload, is there a way to change the window url without refreshing the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Read on AJAX. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Comment: [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method) ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/history)).

Comment: is there a way to do this with simple javascript/jquery functions?

Comment: pushState *is* a simple JavaScript method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0):

probably want to use ajax for this, jquery has a cool function that is pretty versatile:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: this does not change the url o.o